# How to keep elements in a VBox in a ScrollPane from cramming?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm working on a box that logs events that happen in the game I'm creating.
For this I put a VBox in a ScrollPane. This VBox gets filled with GridPanes that for now only contain a Text.

The first few entries are working as intended, but as soon as they reach the max height of the box they start cramming. I want the height to grow with the entries while the entries don't cram.

[First few entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW9FN.png) /
[Crammed entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHPAE.png)

Giving the VBox a huge min height solved the issue, but made the scrollbar too small and I want the box to scroll to the bottom everytime a new entry gets added.
FXML code for the box:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="144.0" prefWidth="430.0" style="-fx-background-color: #a1aaa0;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.catan.Controller.LogController">
   <children>
      <ScrollPane id="logScrollPane" fx:id="scrollPane" hbarPolicy="NEVER" prefHeight="144.0" prefWidth="430.0" stylesheets="@style.css">
         <content>
            <VBox fx:id="logsBox" prefWidth="430.0" prefHeight="144.0" />
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

JavaFX code for the GridPane:

```
    private GridPane logGrid = new GridPane();
    private Text eventText = new Text();
    private HBox imgBox = new HBox();

public void initLogPane(){
        logGrid.prefHeight(25);
        logGrid.prefWidth(430);

        RowConstraints row = new RowConstraints();
        row.setPrefHeight(30);
        row.setMinHeight(10);

        logGrid.getRowConstraints().add(row);

        ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        column1.setMinWidth(10);
        column1.setPrefWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        ColumnConstraints column2 = new ColumnConstraints();
        column2.setMinWidth(10);
        column2.setPrefWidth(84);

        logGrid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(column1, column2);

        eventText.setWrappingWidth(0);
        eventText.setFont(Font.font(13));
        logGrid.setMargin(eventText, new Insets(0, 15, 0, 0));

        imgBox.prefHeight(100);
        imgBox.setSpacing(2);

        logGrid.add(eventText, 0, 0);
        logGrid.add(imgBox, 1, 0);
}
```

Comment: Increase min height for row or gridpane

Comment: You should set the prefHeight of the VBox to USE_COMPUTED_SIZE. (Just delete the prefHeight="144.0" from your FXML-File or make it in Scenebuilder) This should work..

Comment: You might want to consider using a `ListView`.

Comment: Don't hard code sizes.